# How to explain a difference between the test and validation set's distribution of probabilities by a binary classificaion model with probabilities?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, overfitting

I am using Random Forests for a binary classification model, where the output of the model is a score between 0 and 1. The problem is that there is a stark difference between the distribution of my instances with respect to the score between the validation and the test set.

Here are the histograms:

1) Validation Set 
[image: Validation Set score distribution]

2) Test Set
[image: TestSet score distribution]

I can think of two reasons that might explain this:

1) Overfitting, although it is my understanding that RF tends not to overfit

2) The pattern is indeed different for the instances of my test set

I am at a loss as to what might explain this behaviour.

I should also note that when we compared the proportion of 1/0 outcomes for 0.1 buckets between the test and the validation set, the results are also very different

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are your validation and test sets constructed? Did you pull randomly from the full data set, or was there a "special" data set for the test set?

Comment: The validation set comes from data from 2014 to 2017 and the test set is 2018 data. The reason is that the model was used to predict on the 2018 instances